# Lazy loading Angular directives in ui-router as Webpack chunks

Tags: javascript, angularjs, lazy-loading, webpack

I am trying to lazy load an Angular directive as a webpack chunk.

Here is my current config attempt at using **[ocLazyLoad](https://github.com/ocombe/ocLazyLoad)**:

```
// Basic Config
function routingBase( $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $stateProvider ) { 

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/home',
            template: '<app-main></app-main>',
            resolve: {
                load: ( $q, $ocLazyLoad ) => {

                    let deferred = $q.defer(); 

                    require.ensure([], (require) => {

                        // Load entire module
                        let module = require('../modules/main');

                        $ocLazyLoad.load({ 
                            name: module.name 
                        });

                        deferred.resolve(module);

                    }, 'app-main');

                    return deferred.promise;
                }
            }
        })
}
```

This goes in `myModule.config(routingBase);`.

`../modules/main` is just an angular module that exports a directive (e.g. `export default angular.module('main',[]).directive('appMain', appMainFn);`.

Any tips? What I am getting is that the `<app-main></app-main>` is correctly added to the document, and that the chunk is correctly loaded as module. But it is not replaced (it stays as `<app-main></app-main>`).

Would you recommend a different method for lazy loading chunks (maybe using `$compileProvider`)? I would like the cleanest possible way.

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in my current project. Just change the following line and see it works. You need to add **default** as well since you are exporting angular module as default. Cheers!

```
$ocLazyLoad.load({ 
name: module.default.name 
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to change the lazy chunks name? It is always named "this_is_the_path_to_the_lazy_loaded_module_js.js" which is really annoying... I would love to name is something else.